# How to set focused node Devexpress TreeListControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, treelist

I'd like to change the focused node in my TreeListControl via code. For the sake of simplicity, I have this example:

- A grid has two columns, left we have a TreeListControl, and at right there is a Canvas.
- The TreeListControl is populated with nodes corresponding to some shapes in the Canvas (such as the shapes name, etc.).
- What I already have done, is to highlight the shape in the Canvas by selecting the corresponding node in the TreeListControl.
- Now what I'd want to do is the other way around: to change the focused node in the TreeListControl by clicking on a shape in the canvas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use client side 'SetFocusedNodeKey' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the TreeListControl's FocusedRow property to the instance of business object.  In this case, everything should work properly.